# How to set select option value which is from DB with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my project, I want to fetch customer names from DB with ajax . And these names will be set to select option value.

These customer names are:

```
 John
 Snow
 Stack
```

But the result in my web select are all undefined. None of these names is appear in my select tag.

Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_ajax_csc.php",
        data: {stTrnNum:1},
        success:function (dataTrn) 
        {
          alert(dataTrn);
          function callback(data)
          {
            var select = document.getElementById('dlgTrnSlc');
            for (var i in data)
            {
             $(select).append('<option value=' + data[i].customer + '>' + data[i].customer + '</option>');
            }
            $(select).val(data[1].customer);
          }
          callback(dataTrn);  
        } 
       });
```

Here is html code:

```
<div id="dlgTrn" >
<select  id="dlgTrnSlc"></select>
</div>
```

Here is get_ajax_csc.php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['stTrnNum']))
{
 include("DB.php");
 $sql="select customer from IDC;";
 $sel = $conn->query($sql); 
 $arr = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

I have tried

```
$arr = fetch(PDO:FETCH_NUM);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And my js:

```
 var select = document.getElementById('dlgTrnSlc');
        for (var i in data)
        {
         $(select).append('<option value='+data[i]+'>'+data[i]+ '</option>');
        }
        $(select).val(data[1]);
      }
      callback(dataTrn);
```

But it failed again. Who can help me ?

Comment: if your `<option>` value is string, try change to: `$(select).append('<option value="'+data[i]+'">'+data[i]+ '</option>');` (use "...")

Comment: could you write some example json data?  additionally you can use: $('select').append($('', {value:1, text:'One'})); also should be fetchAll()

Comment: `$sel->fetch()` will only return one row from the result set, not all. Also, do a `console.log(data);` in your JS to see what that variable actually contains.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, you are right. But how to return all rows?

Comment: Use [fetchAll(), as described in the manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, it works fine, thankyou very much